# How to stack rectangular prisms in a cross-browser way?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a cube out of shorter, stacked rectangular prisms but have run into some issues. I am not concerned about IE just yet, but I am concerned about the huge difference in rendering between Chrome, FF and Safari.

### Chrome (v44.0.2403.155)

[image: Chrome]

### Safari (v8.0.3)

[image: Safari]

### Firefox (v40.0.2)

[image: Firefox]

Check out the live demo here: http://codepen.io/okeegan/pen/yNWNaw

The basic structure is (edited for brevity):

```
<div class="allsort positioned"><!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="allsort__layer"><!-- Individual prism in cube -->
        <div class="allsort__layer-side bottom"></div><!-- side of prism -->
        <div class="allsort__layer-side left"></div>
        <div class="allsort__layer-side right"></div>
        <div class="allsort__layer-side top"></div>
        <div class="allsort__layer-side front"></div>
        <div class="allsort__layer-side back"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following styles:

```
.page {
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.allsort {
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: all 2s;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.allsort.positioned .allsort__layer.pink-1 {
  transform: translateY(0) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.allsort.positioned .allsort__layer.black-1 {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.allsort.positioned .allsort__layer.cream {
  transform: translateY(16px) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.allsort.positioned .allsort__layer.black-2 {
  transform: translateY(24px) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.allsort.positioned .allsort__layer.pink-2 {
  transform: translateY(30px) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}


  .allsort__layer {
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateY(1000px) rotateX(-45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
  }

    .allsort__layer-side {
      backface-visibility: visible;
      transition: all 400ms;
      transition-delay: 2s;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }

      .allsort__layer-side.top {
        background-color: magenta !important;
        height: 55px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 55px;
      }

      .allsort__layer-side.bottom {
        transform: translateZ(12px);
        background-color: yellow !important;
        height: 55px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 55px;
      }

      .allsort__layer-side.left {
        transform-origin: top center;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        background-color: green !important;
        height: 12px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 55px;
      }

      .allsort__layer-side.right {
        transform-origin: center left;
        transform: rotateY(-90deg);
        background-color: orange !important;
        height: 55px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
      }

      .allsort__layer-side.front {
        transform-origin: top center;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        background-color: blue !important;
        height: 12px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px;
        width: 55px;
      }

      .allsort__layer-side.back {
        transform-origin: center left;
        transform: rotateY(-90deg);
        background-color: red !important;
        height: 55px;
        left: 55px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 12px;
      }
```

I have tried fiddling with the order of side stacking in the HTML with poor results. Are there any obvious problems with my setup? I'm pretty sure I've tried every combo of `transform-style: preserve-3d` and `backface-visibility: visible` possible but maybe there's a secret formula?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.